# Elasticsearch: "must" query on nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

How to do a "must" "match" query on multiple fields under the same nesting? Here's a reproducible ES index where the "user" field is defined as "nested" type.

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "user": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "firstname": {"type": "text"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are 2 documents:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "firstname" : "John"
    },
    {
      "firstname" : "Alice"
    }
  ]
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "firstname" : "Alice"
    }
  ]
}
```

For this index, **how can I query for documents where "John" AND "Alice" both exist**? With the index defined above, I expect to get Document 1 but not Document 2. So far, I've tried the following code, but it's returning no hits:

```
GET my_index/_search 
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"match": {"user.firstname": "John"}},
                        {"match": {"user.firstname": "Alice"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: I'm using Elasticsearch version 7.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below query is what is required.

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "user.firstname": "alice"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "user.firstname": "john"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how I've made use of two nested queries in a single must clause. That is because if you notice the documents that you have `alice` and `john` are both considered `two different documents`.

The query you have would work if your document structure is something like below:

```
POST my_index/_doc/3
{
  "user" : [    
    {
      "firstname" : ["Alice", "John"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Try reading [this (nested datatype)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [this (nested query)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) link to understand more on how they work and from the second link, you can see the below info:

> The nested query searches nested field objects as if they were indexed
>   as separate documents.

Hope that helps!

Comment: With this approach this is impossible to use inner_hits and this is still not possible to make it work this way. If you want to know inner hits I would recommend doing it programmatically: 1) when building query for each nested sub query write inner_hits: { <provide_name>i }, where i - is a count number of subquery. 2) when you receive results merge inner_hits by <provide_name>[i]